# I'm not able to find jar file in mysql-connector.jar.zip

Tags: java

i know this is stupid but strange am not able to find jar..instead am only finding .class files which i cannot put as jar in eclipse.
am extremly frustrated all zips giving .classes only not jar file which i can give as externla jars in eclipse buildpath.

https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&

Comment: oh i see..in my sys every jar file looking like winrar only but not as jar...i got it..some prblem in my sys

Comment: It's not a problem, really. Jar files are in fact zip files. The question is why it also has a `.zip` extension. It shouldn't.

Comment: haha...alien technology am using :P

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Original Download for MSI](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-gpl-5.1.36.msi) or the Linux [zip](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=457912) or [tar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=457911) for the Mysql Connector.